# "We are committed to continually investing in ourselves" or "We are committed to continually invest in ourselves"?

Tags: american-english, past-participles

Which is correct? Also why? For some reason the continually is throwing me off here. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I thought this might be the case, but wasn't sure with the continually thrown in there. Sometimes I don't brain well :)

Comment: Adverbs can appear with ing-forms as well as infinitives. _Brown/Brown's slowly painting his daughter fascinated me._  //  _We need to steadily increase the flow-rate._

Comment: Normally I wouldn't go subsonic, much less ballistic, over a split infinitive, but I suspect that this problem wouldn't be a problem without this one.

Comment: @Rob_Ster Interesting. So, a better formulation would be: "We are continually committed to investing in ourselves."? Any other suggestions?

Comment: @T.Mac It isn't a split infinitive. *To* is a preposition here, followed by an adverb and a bare infinitive. Nothing to split. See the second answer to the question in Edwin's comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are correct, T.Mac. It is the word "continually" that is causing both sample sentences to sound a bit off. To me, continually is used more often with negative connotations, such as, "You are continually annoying me," or "That dog barks continually."

How about "perpetually" or even a simple "always"?